# My cat has been hissing at her sister after 4 years of being with each other

Tags: cats, behavior, health, psychology, veterinarian

I've noticed my cat Azula is hissing at her sister Divina a lot more than usual lately. Of course, cats play with each other and sometimes hiss but they are twin sisters, they've never been separated from each other in the 4 years they've been alive, they've never had problems.

I got them from a woman on Facebook in Cali about 9 months ago. The lady that I got my cats from had said she was giving them away because she's always traveling for months, so she wanted to give them to someone that could give them more time and affection. I got them and moved away from Cali to Washington about 2 months after that, the traveling was perfect.

The last 6-7 months they've been fine, playing with each other just being kitties. I'd say I'm closer with Azula, she's always laying on me or is on my back, sleeping under my covers, looking at me while meowing and I meow back like it's a conversation that goes on for a while. Divina is also a very verbal cat, loves to bet pet and meowed at but isn't all over me like Azula is (like sleeping under my covers.)

Out of nowhere, Azula has started being rude to her sister and hissing every single time she's close to her. I'm usually home, but I got out with friends and come home at night. I also stay at my boyfriend's place for a week sometimes, usually only 4 days, out of every 2 to 3 weeks, but I don't think that is what's wrong, because when I am gone, which has never been longer than a week or so, my friends and family check up on them in my room, feed them and play with them a lot.

When Azula hisses at Divina now I tell her in a stern voice "No don't be mean to her." not yelling, but it makes me worried because I don't want Azula to hurt her. After Azula is rude to Divina I give Azula her space and comfort Divina because I feel she feels that she's getting neglected by her sister.

Can you help me find out what is going on between my cats?

Comment: something must have changed while you were gone i guess. Do you feed them both at the same time? did their eating habbit change? Do they fight all day long? Or only at special locations in the appartment?

OR OR MAYBE AZULA IS sick ?! something is hurting her? She doesn't want her sister to play with her. Did you check your vet?

When my cat is sick and tired sometimes she hisses on her brother to leave her alone. So maybe maybe Azula is a little sick.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that either Azula or Divina could be sick. If Divina is sick, it's possible that Azula is trying to protect you from her sickness, this is very unlikely, due to the fact that it may take years for a cat to care that much about a human. So, I believe that Azula is hissing at Divina, because Azula may be sick, when a cat gets sick,  it tends to act odd/different. I would recommend taking both cats to the Vet and treating them if they are sick.

Another thing that can cause a cat to hiss is, fear, defensiveness, stress, pain, and depression.

More detailed information could be found there:

- [Cat hissing: 7 things that might be to blame](https://www.petmd.com/cat/slideshows/cat-hissing-7-things-might-be-blame) (source: petmd.com).
- [A cat's response to a sick & dying cat](https://pets.thenest.com/cats-response-sick-dying-cat-11114.html) (source: pets.thenest.com).